# Текущее время больше заданного

Tags: python

Как реализовать простое условие? `True`, если `datetime.datetime.now() > '16:00'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
my_time = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
now > my_time    # Если сейчас больше 16:00 будет True
now == my_time   # Если сейчас 16:00 будет True
now < my_time    # Если сейчас меньше 16:00 будет True
```